# iPhone app crashes when changing views after using overridden init method

Tags: ios, objective-c, dictionary, mapquest

So what I'm doing is trying to pass a `MQMapView` from one view controller to the next using:

```
MapSearchView *controller = [[MapSearchView alloc] initWithNibName:@"MapSearchView" bundle:nil mapToDisplay:map];

[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:NO];
```

And what I'm doing in my `MapSearchView`.m is overriding the `init` method:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil mapToDisplay:(MQMapView*)map
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        [self setMapView:map];
    }
    return self;
}
```

I'm passing the `MQMapView` between views because I have some planned functionality that will need to be done to the map in the first view.

The issue I'm having is that once `controller` is assigned it gets passed to `presentModalViewController` and the app crashes there. I can't seem to find any reason for it. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the error it is showing?

Comment: What is the crashlog saying? Can you please post it? Try this also, `mapView = [map retain];` instead of `[self setMapView:map];`

Comment: Post the crashlog please

Comment: you add [self setMapView:map] in viewdidload or loadview

Comment: Right off the top of my head, I'm not sure what could be happening -- but just wanted to add that a newer version of the MQ iOS SDK has been posted for download, so if all else fails, maybe try the new version of the toolkit?

Comment: Here is the exception that gets thrown:
'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/macuser/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications/BB60BE6D-F7E6-4F2A-8203-1CF70251BB62/FareFriend.app> (loaded)' with name 'MapSearchView''

And thanks jharahush, I'll try the update and see if that fixes anything at all. Although I think my issue is specific to Objective-C.

Comment: @NANNAV but if '[self setMapView:map]' is in 'viewDidLoad' how does 'setMapView' gain access to 'map'? 'map' is being passed into the overridden 'init' method. Does 'map' become global to the class once it's passed in and the class is initialized?

Comment: Tried one or two work arounds, crash still isn't solved. Exception message is posted two comments above this one. Any suggestions/ideas?

Comment: Looks to me like there's a problem with the NIB.  Does MapSearchView.xib even exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the xib file could not be found

**Change this line**

```
MapSearchView *controller = [[MapSearchView alloc] initWithNibName:@"MapSearchView" bundle:nil mapToDisplay:map];
```

**to be**

```
MapSearchView *controller = [[MapSearchView alloc] initWithNibName:@"MapSearchView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle] mapToDisplay:map];
```

---

Another thing ... Check the name of the xib file `MapSearchView`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Looks like it should work but unfortunately I can't test it, I sold my Mac a while ago and I'm out of iOS development for the time being. If I get back to it I'll give that a try. :)